# $ X_1,...,X_n $ independent and identically distributed. Show inequalities.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $ X_1,...,X_n$ be independent and identically distributed random variables with values in $\mathbb{N} $ and probability function $p(k) = \frac{1}{k(k+1)}$.

Calculate:

a) $P(X_1 \ge k) $

b)$P(max(X_1,...,X_n) \ge k) $

c) the probability function of the  random variable $ M_n$ := max{$X_1,...,X_n$}

d) Show that $P( M_n > \lambda \cdot n ) $ convergences for every $\lambda$ $ > 0$. What's the limit?

Attempt:

a)$ P(X_1 \ge k) = \sum_{x=k} P(X_1=x) = \sum_{x=k} \frac{1}{k(k+1)} = \sum_{x=k} \frac{1}{k} -\frac{1}{k+1} = 1 - (1- \frac{1}{k})= \frac{1}{k}$ .

b) I'm not sure if I understand b), because I could say that$ X_j := max(X_1,...,X_n)$, couldn't I? Then it is analogous to a). Where is my mistake here? **Edit** : b) is clear now. found my mistake.

c) I know that I have to use b).

d) $P( M_n > \lambda \cdot n ) $ = $\sum_{m > \lambda \cdot n} P(M_n = m)$ = $\sum_{m > \lambda \cdot n} \frac{1}{m(m+1)}$ = ? . Now this a telescoping series,right? I'm stucked, here. **Edit2** I know that this isn't right. Have to use b) again.

Do I have mistakes?

Answer (score 1):

Although the maximum $M_n$ will have the same value one of the $X_j$ by definition, it will not have the same distribution as a particular $X_j$. As a thought experiment, imagine drawing $n=1000$ or $n=10000$ i.i.d. samples, computing the maximum $M_n$, and think about the probability $P(M_n=1)$. Do you see why it does not intuitively make sense for $P(M_n=1)=P(X_1=1)$?

b) Try rewriting the event $\{\max(X_1,\ldots,X_n) < k\}$ as $\{X_1 < k\} \cap \cdots \cap \{X_n < k\}$.

For c) and d), use the result of part b).

Comment: How embarrassing! Found my mistake in b).  Thank your for your description. solved b) now. Unfortunately I'm stucked in c) and d). Could I consider $ P( M_n = y ) = P(M_n \ge y) - P(M_n \ge y+1) $?

Comment: @Mugumble For c), yes, that's exactly right. For d), just write down the result of b) for an appropriately chosen $k$, and see how the expression changes as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

For b):

It is more easy to see $\Bbb P(\text{max}(X_1,\dots, X_n)) < k$

Comment: solved b) now ! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I hope the image is clear and legible

[image]

Comment: @ Satish Ramanathan: First of all: Thank you for your reply. I understand b) now and found my mistake. Unfortunately I'm a beginner in probability theory. So It is forbidden to use the derivate or the the integral. Is there another possibility to solve c) and d)? Nevertheless your solution is awesome!